# How to know when a Web Worker has been terminated?

Tags: web-worker

Is there a way to know when a Web Worker has been terminated?

You can do this:
const worker = new Worker('example.com/worker')

```
worker.terminate()

worker.postMessage('yo') // This still works, but the worker is gone. Why?
```

After a worker has been terminated, there's not really a good way to know. Seems like you can still post to it and all your event listeners are still active. Is it possible for us to look at the `worker` object and see if it's been terminated?

Comment: There is an active discussion to maybe add a close event to Web Workers. I remembered your question and was wondering about your use-case as this may help design it better.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, *apart from a bug exploit in Firefox*.

No event is fired, the Worker object doesn't have any property letting us know, everything should just fail silently.

The only solution would be to override both `Worker.terminate()` and `DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope.close()` in order for these to let you know about it.

Here is a proof of concept:

```js
class StateAwareWorker extends Worker {
  constructor( ...args ) {
    super( ...args );
    this.terminated = false;
    this.addEventListener( 'error', ( evt ) => {
      if( evt.message && evt.message.endsWith( "closing" ) ) {
        evt.stopImmediatePropagation(); // don't let other scripts know about it
        evt.preventDefault(); // don't verbose in console
        Object.defineProperty( this, "terminated", { value: true } );
      }
    } );
  }
  terminate() {
    Object.defineProperty( this, "terminated", { value: true } );
    Worker.prototype.terminate.call( this );
  }
}


const url = generateWorkerURL();

const closing_worker = new StateAwareWorker( url );
closing_worker.postMessage( 'close' ); // closing internally
setTimeout( ()=> {
  console.log( 'closed worker is terminated:', closing_worker.terminated );
}, 200 );

const terminated_worker = new StateAwareWorker( url );
terminated_worker.terminate(); // closing from here
setTimeout( ()=> {
  console.log( 'terminated worker is terminated:', terminated_worker.terminated );
}, 200 );

const open_worker = new StateAwareWorker( url );
// not closing
setTimeout( ()=> {
  console.log( 'keep-open worker is terminated:', open_worker.terminated );
}, 200 );

function generateWorkerURL() {
  const script = document.querySelector( "[type='worker-script']" );
  const blob = new Blob( [ script.textContent ], { type: "text/javascript" } );
  return URL.createObjectURL( blob );
}
```

```html
<script type="worker-script">
  // override self.close top let the other-side know we're closing
  {
    const original = self.close;
    self.close = () => {
      setTimeout( () => original.call( self ), 0 );
      throw new Error( "closing" );
    };
  }

  // close the Worker at first message received
  onmessage = () => {
    self.close();
  };
</script>
```

And for the curious using Firefox, here is the "exploit" I talked about, but don't use it, it may not work in a few releases:

```js
// current Firefox doesn't throw a DOMException 
// when the Worker holding the other PortMessage is terminated
// we can exploit this "bug" (?) to know if the Worker is terminted or not
function isTerminated( worker ) {
  try {
    worker.postMessage(()=>{});
    return true;
  }
  catch(e){ return false; }
}
console.warn( 'This demo works only on Firefox' );
const worker_url = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob() );
const worker = new Worker( worker_url );
console.log( isTerminated( worker ) ); // false
worker.terminate(); // would also work if closed from inside
console.log( isTerminated( worker ) ); // true
```