# Detect when webworker closed

Tags: javascript, web-worker, deno

I am using the Worker API from Deno, which looks like its the same as the browser web worker API.

My question is, how to handle worker process closing from the parent process?

```
const worker = new Worker(...);

worker.onclose = () => console.log("worker closed"); // never runs
worker.onerror = () => console.log("error in worker");
```

there doesn't seem to be a "onclose" event.

there is an "onerror" event which i am not sure it runs if a worker process quits for other reasons except error (not sure if it should be able to quit for other reasons).

But the main issue with `onerror` is that when worker closes because of an error, the host process closes too. Is there a way to catch the error and be able to restart worker?

All this is possible with the nodejs's child process apis, but since I switched to Deno I am stuck with the Worker apis

---

I did some more research and it appears that the host is killed because of the `--watch` Deno argument.

And I was able to catch the errors in the worker by using:

```
globalThis.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  globalThis.postMessage({command: "exit", error: event.error});
});
```

Then in the host when I receive the "exit" command, I kill the worker:

```
worker.onmessage = (event) => {
  const { command, error } = event.data;
  if(command === "exit"){
     worker.terminate();

     if(error{
       setTimeout(() => restartWorker(), 5000);
     }

  }
}
```

Unfortunately this is hard to test due to the --watch issue above:(

And I am still not sure this is the right way to do it, because sub-processes can die for many reasons, and if there is a situation where the error event listener and exit postMessage is not fired in the worker, I would be left with an unstable state of the host process.

Comment: What could cause your Worker to be terminated without you terminating it yourself? Also, for browsers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903597/how-to-know-when-a-web-worker-has-been-terminated/62906818#62906818 And your question about `onerror` isn't clear. To catch the error, you'd listen to that error event, e.g through that `onerror` property or through `addEventListener`. Oh.. now I see you mention the "host" is killed too o_0 that's pretty bad. No time to check right now but I will tomorrow.

Comment: I was thinking like another process on the server forcibly killing the worker process? Or maybe a memory errors, or something that would prevent any further communication with the host

Comment: Well if it's caused by an error (e.g memory error), an error event should be dispatched to the Worker object, if it's your code (even from another process) that does terminate it, you should be able to handle it, as for blocking the comunication, that's a bit too vague for me to comprehend. And checking quickly at deno's issues it seems that error reports are being tested so I doubt it kills the host. Could you share an [mre]?

Comment: I believe it is related to this issue: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/7590. Basically when you run `deno --watch script.ts`  the script will be killed when an error is thrown in the worker that is called from it. If I add the event listener for error in the worker then this does not happen anymore, but I get weird behaviour after the error, like script starting by itself, ports showing as being busy

Comment: No, there's no API for responding to the termination of a worker. A workaround might be to create a simple pulse check message and then react appropriately (here's a naïve/contrived example: https://tsplay.dev/wXOVoW). Does that address your question? If so, I can write it up as an answer — if not, what am I missing?

Comment: could be an option, but doesn't that waste cpu cycles on the main thread? My use case is a server manager app that will open multiple workers to do various things, like sftp, and I need the main thread to be as free as possible

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75705559/detect-when-webworker-closed?noredirect=1#comment133622615_75705559) @Alex Workers aren't the only way to do work off the main thread. Deno has multiple sub-process APIs — e.g. [`Deno.Command`](https://deno.land/api@v1.31.2?s=Deno.Command), [`Deno.run`](https://deno.land/api@v1.31.2?s=Deno.run)